# Pause and resume execution of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

There are two processes(p1, p2) that may run simultaneously. p2 is a scheduled execution of SPROC while p1 consists of a group of stored procedures that is triggered on the request.
Execution of p1 while p2 is in progress can create issues. Only one should run at a time.
There are three ways to solve this problem

1. When p1 starts check whether p2 is in progress and wait until it completes. p2 can run for more than a day and it might not be a preferable solution
2. Kill p2, complete p1 and then restart p2. Killing and restarting p2 isn't safe due to nature of the sproc
3. pause p2 and resume p2 when p1 completes

Questions

**1. How can I search and stop store procedure being executed?**

**2. Is there any way I can pause and resume a stored procedure that is being executed?**

Comment: Does `p2` have multiple queries in it, or just one query that runs for a long time?

Comment: This is what transactions are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no clean way to just pause and resume a stored procedure, but you can have it sleep for a fixed period of time using [`WAITFOR DELAY 'XX:YY:ZZ'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (where X is replaced with hours, Y minutes, and Z seconds for how long you want the thread to sleep).

It really depends on what **p2** is doing and if there's multiple batches of queries you can break up with a check for if **p1** is running. If **p2** is just one single long running query then you won't be able to pause it when **p1** starts, you'd only be able to make **p1** wait until **p2** was finished. (In this case you shouldn't have a single query running as long as a day though, so I'd recommend optimizing **p2** anyway.)

If you do have a way to break up the queries in **p2** then you can periodically check if **p1** is running between each batch of queries, use a `WHILE` loop and the aforementioned `WAITFOR DELAY` to sleep the thread (whatever time  amount is acceptable to you) of **p2**, checking if **p1** is done running on each iteration of the `WHILE` loop.

I don't think there's a perfect solution if you're trying to avoid any overlap, but if some overlap of the jobs is ok then you should be able to rig something with the above up.

You might be able to help prevent any data overlap (at the cost of potentially making **p1** wait a mininal amount of time) by using transactions around each batch of queries in **p2** that way **p1** will have to wait until **p2** finishes it's active transaction. If you want to avoid overlap for performance reasons instead, then you'll need to implement a check system in **p1** as well to loop and sleep while waiting on **p2** to finish it's current query batch before it sleeps itself once it checks **p1** is now running.

Comment: second the idea of breaking p2 into batches. There may also be a role for using application locks see for example https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-sp_getapplock-and-sp_releaseapplock-stored-procedures/